# Geomesa accumulo storing null Point for geometry

Tags: geotools, jts-topology-suite, geomesa

I am using `Point` geometry type in geomesa for strong lat-long details in feature type. In one of the use case while storing a new feature I don't have value for lat-long so I tried sending `null` object for `createPoint` function, but the library 'jts' throwing exception while processing null Geometry type. [Here](https://github.com/simplegeo/jts/blob/master/src/com/vividsolutions/jts/geom/Point.java#L117-L119) is the source code. By seeing the implementation of `jts`library, It seems difficult for storing null in geomesa Point. What are the possibilities I can go for?
Here is the snapshot of my code:

```
sf.setAttribute(Attributes.GEOMETRY.getValue(), JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory().createPoint((Coordinate)null/*new Coordinate(event.lat, event.lng)*/));
```

Attaching logs for exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: getX called on empty Point
    at com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point.getX(Point.java:124)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.uuid.Z3UuidGenerator$.createUuid(Z3FeatureIdGenerator.scala:93)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.uuid.Z3UuidGenerator$.createUuid(Z3FeatureIdGenerator.scala:70)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.uuid.Z3FeatureIdGenerator.createId(Z3FeatureIdGenerator.scala:32)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaFeatureWriter$.featureWithFid(GeoMesaFeatureWriter.scala:64)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaFeatureWriter.writeFeature(GeoMesaFeatureWriter.scala:128)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.index.geotools.GeoMesaAppendFeatureWriter$class.write(GeoMesaFeatureWriter.scala:194)
    at org.locationtech.geomesa.accumulo.data.AccumuloAppendFeatureWriter.write(AccumuloFeatureWriter.scala:19)
    at com.hps.GeomesaClient.insert(GeomesaClient.java:129)
```

Answer (score 1):

Something else must be throwing your null pointer exception - I can run the following:

```
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;

import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point;

public class EmptyGeom {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    Point p = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory().createPoint((Coordinate)null/*new Coordinate(event.lat, event.lng)*/);
    System.out.println(p);
  }

}
```

which gives the expected result of:

```
POINT EMPTY
```

Comment: The exception is thrown while calling getX on empty point, not on creating an empty point. Sorry for the late attachments of log.

Comment: looks like geomesa's `org.locationtech.geomesa.utils.uuid.Z3UuidGenerator`  needs an `isEmpty` check